Is there a way to get unicode characters as well as ANSI Escape codes from the user in C++?
I am trying to create a function that read keystrokes in POSIX from the input stream that are unicode characters without pressing enter, nonCanonical mode, and I managed to get that working however I can't seem to figure out a way to get escape codes from the input stream such as the arrow keys, ^[[A ^[[B ^[[C ^[[D or just the ESC key.
So far what I have that I found and modified on a forum:
int _get_key() {
    int buf = 0;
    fflush(stdout);
    if(read(0, &buf, sizeof(buf)) < 0)
        perror("read()");
    return buf;
}

wchar_t get_key() {
    wchar_t buf_src[16] = {0};
    int ch = _get_key();
    memcpy(buf_src, &ch, sizeof(ch));

    wchar_t buf_dest[16] = {0};
    mbstowcs(buf_dest, buf_src, 1);

    return buf_dest[0];
}

This works just fine getting a single character but I cannot figure out how to parse an escape code

The human representation ^[[A actually means the three literal bytes ESC (0x1b), [ (0x5b) and A (0x41). Also note that 'unicode characters' cannot be entered. If you are on macOS it is extremely likely that your user is sending you the UTF-8 encoded representation of a unicode character, which potentially spans multiple bytes. Which means it is very wrong to cast a single byte of a UTF-8 stream to wchar_t and expect something sensible. And that is before we get into the mess that is surrogate characters...

The code exhibits undefined behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

So you want to parse escape codes, what's wrong with starting with ch = get_key(); if (ch == 27) ... (27 being the value of the escape character). I'm not really sure what the issue is, more details are needed on the actual issue you are facing.

Hmm okay, so what actually is a wchar_t and how do I store a UTF-8?

Time to go read the absolute classic The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)

You need to make your parser stateful so it can detect the start of a multibyte sequence and remember where it is in the sequence. For ANSI escapes the length of the sequence is determined by the second character after the escape character, for UTF-8 you need to distinguish between ASCII, start bytes, and continuation bytes
